# What is the best example of a “conspiracy theory” that years later turned out to actually be true?

Tags: social-history

I’m thinking about years later operation MKUltra was disclosed, which is sort of something you might find far-fetched when you first heard it. Another may be speculations about motivations for the War in Iraq later being confirmed.

But these are not great examples. I mean something that would be dismissed as a conspiracy theory, and some time later, probably on the scale of decades if not centuries, it turned out to be true.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because Conspiracy theories are [off topic](https://history.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic#:~:text=Conspiracy%20Theories%20or%20Pseudo%2Dscience) on this site.

Comment: Even if this is on topic (borderline in my opinion), how do you define 'best example'? I think you'll need to do some editing to prevent this being closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Have there been government conspiracies that were successful for over 25 years?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/55260/have-there-been-government-conspiracies-that-were-successful-for-over-25-years)

Comment: Both of the ones I can think of off the top of my head (the secret parts of the Moltov-Ribbentrop Pact, and the Reagan campaign's collusion with Iran on keeping the hostages during the 1980 election) were actually kind of obvious at the time. Conspirators generally aren't that great at hiding what they are doing. (If they were smart, they wouldn't need to be sneaky)